# Populate extension point's element attribute during runtime

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Here is my use case. I have an Editor that different plugins can use to display their data. These plugins can create (with intervention from user - wizards) different files that Editor can accept: .p1, .p2, etc. Each plugin contributes file extensions of files that it produces and this data is available via custom extension point. I need a way, if possible to "inject" this data into **org.eclipse.ui.editors** extension point's **extensions** attribute.

One way I was thinking about doing this is in a plugin that is called early enough collect file extensions from all plugins that use my extension point and write these values into plugin.properties file's key like supportedFileExtension and extension point org.eclipse.ui.editors will in turn consume this file:

```
 <extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
<editor
      class="MyEditor"
      contributorClass="MyActionBarContributor"
      default="false"
      extensions="%supportedFileExtensions"
      id="my.com.editor"
      name="My Editor">
</editor>
```

I also saw class ExtensionParameterValues which is something I can possibly use, but for developer who might want to reuse this little mechanism, it might not be obvious enough what's going, especially when extensions attribute would be empty when using ExtensionParameterValues class. Of course I can put this in documentation, but who reads that, right? :)

Perhaps I am overlooking something simple and there is an easier way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are all the file extension ones that you define rather than any existing ones (like .txt)?

Comment: Yes, extensions are all different and not what's provided by platform by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using extensions directly you can Eclipse Content Types to do this. First define a base content type:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
  <content-type
        id="contenttype.base"
        name="Base content type"/>
```

Then your different plugins can define a content type for their file extensions using a a content type derived from the base type:

```xml
  <content-type
        base-type="contenttype.base"
        file-extensions="p1"
        id="contenttype.p1"
        name="P1 content type"/>

  <content-type
        base-type="contenttype.base"
        file-extensions="p2"
        id="contenttype.p2"
        name="P2 content type"/>
```

For your editor don't specify any extensions, instead use the `contentTypeBinding` for the base type:

```xml
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
     class="MyEditor"
     contributorClass="MyActionBarContributor"
     default="false"
     id="my.com.editor"
     name="My Editor">
   <contentTypeBinding
           contentTypeId="contenttype.base"/> 
   </editor>
```

The editor will now be used for all content types based on the base content type.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is something I can definitely use. One question, do I need to define base content type or can I reuse one already defined - org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml since all my files are XML files?

Comment: You can use the existing XML content type.

Comment: got little of trouble here. I've defined my base content type so that I can catch all extensions I need and defined binding in editor ext point. However when I load instance of Eclipse I can't see my editor as default for files. File Extensions are loaded in Content Types preference page, but not in File Associations. When I add bind file extension and editor manually, I get error Could not create content describer for my.com.inlet. Content type has been disabled. Here is pastie http://pastebin.mozilla.org/4648223. I googled for this, but nothing substantial I can see.

Comment: After I restarted Eclipse instance while cleaning runtime workspace, the file associations started working...